# Animations not working when Famous (Famo.us) app wrapped in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, transition, famo.us

I tried wrapping a sample famo.us app using Phonegap and created an apk using build.phonegap.com.
For some reason, the animations/transitions are not showing up. The app loads correctly with all resources properly showing up (images, famous surfaces). Its only the animations that have disappeared.

Interestingly, I tried locally testing the Famous app by installing "Phonegap Developer" app from playStore (both iOS and Android). In this everything works perfectly, animations are rendered exactly like the desktop browser.

I have also tried locally saving all famous files without using famous CDN. But this didn't effect anything except for the load time, ofcourse.

Any ideas how to make the transitions work on a famous-phonegap app?

Thanks!

Comment: Some quick questions Have you used grunt build and then moved the contents of the dist folder into your www folder in your phonegap project?

Comment: Hello Kraig, thanks for the suggestion. Trying out grunt now (never used it before). I guess this is a good place to start - https://github.com/Famous/famous

Comment: Thanks @KraigWalker. I did not use grunt/yo-famous earlier. But now I realise grunt generator-famous is the way to go! It couldn't be any easier than 'moving the dist folder contents to www folder of phonegap'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a wild assumption you started out with the generator famous project. It's something I've really come to rely on, and even take for granted. The build tool uses requires and concats all your js files and the parts of famous that are actually used by your app into one js file. It's totally possible get famous apps in phonegap. (I know cause mine do with little effort)